# Create a listbox from code and style list items

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have this code to create a listbox on my Menu.xaml code behind (Menu.xaml.vb):

```
Dim mm as new ListBox()
mm.FontSize=20
mm.Items.add("Notifications:")
For Each Row as DataRow in mydt.Rows
  mm.Items.add(Row("name"))
Next
```

The code works great and I can see the list box but what I want is to style each listbox item. For example I want the first one with fontsize=24, fontbold, backcolor=black, font color white and the rest with fontsize=16

There is no listbox on the xaml, it is created and painted by code.

Any help or clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't stylize single items in a ListBox. You may want to use a ListView instead.

Comment: ok. It doen´t matter what control to use, but whats about the code?

Comment: @JohnWillemse, any reason items can be stylized in `ListView`, but not in `ListBox`? By stylizing, do you mean the `View` property of `ListView`?

Comment: @publicgk No, I meant font & colors, but then again I was proven wrong by Clemens in his answer below... I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explicitly create a [ListBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611063.aspx) for every item and set all necessary properties. In C# it may look like shown below (sorry, i don't speak VB).

```
mm.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem
{
    Content = "Item 1",
    Foreground = Brushes.White,
    Background = Brushes.Black,
    FontSize = 24,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
});
mm.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem
{
    Content = "Item 2",
    FontSize = 16
});
...
```